# Combine rows where duplicate values exist in one column

Tags: vba, excel

I need help combining rows with VBA in Excel dynamically where the value is sometimes the same in one column.

Sample Data

```
A B C   D   E
1 r 10  5   3
1 r 12  8   2
2 q 60  50  40
2 q 25  45  55
2 q 100 200 300
```

EDIT: mistake in my sample data, changed last value in A from 3 to 2.

Ideally, I would combine the rows where the value is the same below in column `B` and while combining the values in C & D separated by semi colon and summing the values in column E.

It works when there is one duplicate, but not varying numbers of duplicates (dynamic combining)

Here is basically what I have tried:

```
Dim i As Long
i = 2

For i = 2 to lastRow
    If Cells(i, 2).Value = Cells(i + 1, 2).Value Then
        Cells(i, 3).Value = Cells(i, 3).Value & ";" & Cells(i + 1, 3).Value
        Cells(i, 4).Value = Cells(i, 4).Value + Cells(i + 1, 4).Value
        Rows(i + 1).Delete
    Else
        i = i + 1
    End If
Loop
```

Comment: The `For` loop increments `i` by itself. If `i = i + 1` is executed, `i` is incremented by 2 in that iteration. Instead you'd need to decrement `i` after deleting a row or use a `Do While` loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can work backwards.  Before:

[image]

The sub:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim i As Long
    lastRow = 5

    For i = lastRow To 2 Step -1
        If Cells(i, 2).Value = Cells(i - 1, 2).Value Then
            Cells(i - 1, 3).Value = Cells(i - 1, 3).Value & ";" & Cells(i, 3).Value
            Cells(i - 1, 4).Value = Cells(i - 1, 4).Value + Cells(i, 4).Value
            Rows(i).Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

and after:

[image]

Comment: Why backwards? Does this work if there are "n" number of duplicates, so sometimes only 2, sometimes none, sometimes 4, 5,6?

Comment: @MJ95 If you go from top to bottom you will encounter empty lines towards the end (because you deleted some) and it will end in an infinite loop (well until the cell is filled with the maximum numbers of semicolons I guess) unless you check if you arrived at the end in every iteration. Going backwards also adds the benefit that you don't have to worry about adjusting `i`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do what you want.

```
Sub Macro()
Dim lngRow As Long
For lngRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
If StrComp(Range("B" & lngRow), Range("B" & lngRow - 1), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
If Range("C" & lngRow) <> "" Then
Range("C" & lngRow - 1) = Range("C" & lngRow - 1) & "|" & Range("C" & lngRow) & _
    Range("D" & lngRow - 1) & ";" & Range("D" & lngRow)
End If
Rows(lngRow).Delete
End If
Next

    Columns("D:E").Select
    Selection.ClearContents

End Sub
```